# Child view focus in MVVM application to see Command

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, command

I am developing an MVVM application. I have a main Window, which looks more or less like this:

```
<Window>
   <ContentControl Content={Binding ContentViewModel} />
</Window>
```

Then I have this ViewModel, which exposes a certain number of Commands, and I want these commands to be available to the user both from the UI (with buttons, etc), AND from the keyboard, using KeyBindings.

The commands work properly from the UI buttons. But the Keybindings don't always work, it'd seem to me that the problem is that the loaded view is not always in focus.
This is the code for the view.

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding RemoveEntityCommand,  ElementName=Designer}" />
    </UserControl.InputBindings>
    <Grid>
        <namespace:Designer x:Name="Designer" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

How to solve this permanently for an MVVM application? I've encountered this problem multiple times.

Note: all namespace declarations removed for simplicity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably attach a Command to the KeyDown or KeyUp event of the `Window` instead of the `UserControl`, and route it from there.

It can either be routed to the `ShellViewModel`, which will in turn pass it to the current `ContentViewModel` if needed, or perhaps use some kind of Messaging system that broadcasts special key combinations, and ViewModel's can subscribe to them.

Comment: So no way to get focus from XAML?

Comment: I don't think you can set focus on multiple objects at once unless they're in different Focus Scopes. Are you looking to restrict focus to only your `UserControl` when it is visible?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is implement a PreviewKeyUp event and use that to call a method on my view model, something like this:

```
protected void PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs args) 
{
    args.Handled = myViewModel.HandleKeyUp(args.Key);
}

public bool HandleKeyUp(Key key) 
{
   // Determine if you should execute a command
   if(myCommands.ShouldExecuteOnKey(key))
   {
       // Execute the commad
       return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

A lot of people seem to think that MVVM means *no code-behind*, but that's not always true, or even possible.

Comment: I'm comfortable with using code behind, as long as it's the only way, I prefer to use the elements the way they are intended, I can also replace Commands with custom code behind logic, but there is a much more comfortable way, so I stick with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, key bindings are a pain. And I agree with Rachel that you likely want something available at the window level in this specific case.

You *can* avoid code behind and get the goodness of mvvm by doing the following:

1. make your commands aware of key gestures
2. give a KeyBinding an additional property that takes advantage of (1)

This is obviously a bit of infrastructure work tho it is testable and reusable once you have it in place. In this case, since you want the bindings available at the window level, your ShellVm holds the commands and delegates to child view models as needed. I've left just enough code below to give you a feel for the idea

HTH,
Berryl

## sample bindings

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <cmdRef:KeyBindingEx  CommandReference="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

## extended KeyBinding

```
public class KeyBindingEx : KeyBinding
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandReferenceProperty = DependencyProperty
        .Register("CommandReference", typeof(CommandReference), typeof(KeyBindingEx),          
                  new PropertyMetadata(OnCommandReferenceChanged));

    private static void OnCommandReferenceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        var kb = (KeyBinding) d;
        var cmdRef = e.NewValue as VmCommand;
        if(cmdRef==null) return;

        kb.Key = cmdRef.GestureKey;
        kb.Modifiers = cmdRef.GestureModifier;
        kb.Command = cmdRef;
    }

    public CommandReference CommandReference
    {
        get { return (CommandReference)GetValue(CommandReferenceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandReferenceProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

## Command Reference base class extract

public class CommandReference : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        ...

```
    public Key GestureKey
    {
        get { return _gestureKey; }
        set
        {
            if (_gestureKey == value) return;

            _gestureKey = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => GestureKey);
        }
    }
    private Key _gestureKey;        
}

/// <summary>A command whose primary purpose is to relay its functionality to other objects by invoking delegates.</summary>
public class VmCommand : CommandReference, ICommand
{
    ...

    /// <summary>Action to be called when the Execute method of the command gets called</summary>
    public Action ExecuteDelegate { get; protected set; }

    /// <summary>Predicate to execute when the CanExecute of the command gets called (default is <c>true</c>)</summary>
    public Func<bool> CanExecuteDelegate { get; protected set; }

}
```